# Turtle tracer arguments example trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

What is the exact usage of Turtle.tracer? In python docs it is written `Turn turtle animation on/off and set delay for update drawings.` I use it for disabling animation but the arguments are not clear for example in this code if I use turtle.trace turtle doesn't draw rest of table how to set correct arguments.

```
import turtle
turtle.width(5)
yd=xd=-64
turtle.tracer(8,25)#This is the problem
for i in range(2):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(-197.5,yd)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.seth(0)
    turtle.fd(394)
    yd+=128
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(xd,197.5)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.seth(270)
    turtle.fd(394)
    xd+=128
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`turtle.delay(0)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.delay):

```
import turtle
turtle.width(5)
yd=xd=-64
turtle.delay(0) # <----
for i in range(2):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(-197.5,yd)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.seth(0)
    turtle.fd(394)
    yd+=128
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(xd,197.5)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.seth(270)
    turtle.fd(394)
    xd+=128
turtle.mainloop()
```

Or use [`turtle.update`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.update) if you use `turtle.tracer`:

```
...
turtle.tracer(8,25)
for i in range(2):
    ...
turtle.update()
tracer.mainloop()
```

Comment: tracer.update()  ... Really?  There's no 'tracer' defined. Have you run this code???  Also,  in https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.update, it says: 
turtle.update():  Perform a TurtleScreen update. To be used when tracer is turned off. 
Godssake! (Yet, I don't downvote your reply because I don't do that. Comments are much more useful than downvoting, which it is often incorrect!)

Comment: @Apostolos, `tracer` comes from OP's code. I ran code without any attribute error. https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer (Did you type `tracer(..)` instead of `turtle.tracer(..)` ?

Comment: @Apostolos, tracer is turned off after n (8 in the above code) drawings according to documentation. No drawings are done after that; manual `update` call is required to draw rest of drawings.

Comment: @Apostolos, With `update`: https://i.imgur.com/8EMSkg3.png, without `update`: https://i.imgur.com/hkYlI1U.png

Comment: I don't know whar you are talking about.  tracer.update() raises "NameError: name 'tracer' is not defined". And I didn't type anyting. I copy-pasted the code, as I always do, so that I avoid typing errors accidentally.

Comment: @Apostolos, I'm sorry. I mis-read your comment. Thank you for pointing the error. Updated the code in the answer to fix the issue: `tracer.update()` -> `turtle.update()`

Comment: OK, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the exact usage of Turtle.tracer? ... I use it for disabling
>   animation but the arguments are not clear...

The function of the `tracer()` method of the turtle screen singleton (also exposed as a top level function) is easy to understand, but it's arguments aren't.  The default settings are:

```
turtle.tracer(1, 10)
```

Let's deal the optional second argument first.  It is simply passed onto the `delay()` method of the turtle screen singleton as a convenience.  From there it is passed onto turtle's TK underpinnings.  Since this answer is about `tracer()` I'll not discuss `delay()` here.

I see two ways to use `tracer()`.  The more complicated is to supply a numeric value `n` that tells turtle to only perform every nth update instead of every update.  This depends on you having a deep understanding of your drawing code to know, for example, you ony need to update every 257th time.  And have a sense when updates actually occur.  For most of us, that's simply not the case.

The simpler way to use `tracer()` is with one boolean argument (posing as a number) and in conjunction with the `update()` function:

```
tracer(False)  # turn off visible drawing

for ...:
    ...  # draw stuff
    update()  # update the visible drawing now
...
tracer(True)  # return to normal drawing
```

A couple of things to note: 1) the `clear()` method of the turtle screen singleton resets `tracer()` to its default values; 2) some turtle commands, like `end_fill()`, may cause updates to occur regardless of your tracer settings.

Your code reworked using the simpler model of `tracer()`:

```
import turtle

yd = xd = -64

turtle.width(5)
turtle.tracer(False)

for i in range(2):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-197.5, yd)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.forward(394)

    yd += 128

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(xd, 197.5)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(394)

    xd += 128

    turtle.update()  # only display completed lines

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.tracer(True)
turtle.mainloop()
```